# g++ undefined reference to library symbols

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, undefined-reference

There are linker errors to Symbols defined by SFML, but i cannot see how they occur despite that I linked the lib.
I'm using make, which I currently learn and I want to build a minimalistic dev-environment with it.

Give a holler if you need anymore information than the following. I'd just like to minimize the questions size.

```sh
XXX@XXX ~/Documents/dev/cpp/proj/beep $ make clean                                                                                                         
rm -f build/*.o build/release/*.o build/debug/*.o build/test/*.o
XXX@XXX ~/Documents/dev/cpp/proj/beep $ make tests
//test obj first
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pthread -Iinclude   -c test/Packager.ut.cpp -o   build/test/Packager.ut.o -g3
//now the src obj 
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pthread -Iinclude   -c src/ClientAddress.cpp -o build/debug/ClientAddress.o -g3
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pthread -Iinclude   -c src/Packager.cpp -o build/debug/Packager.o -g3  
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pthread -Iinclude   -c src/Package.cpp -o build/debug/Package.o -g3
Built debug object files.
//now the first test itself
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pthread -Iinclude  -lsfml-network  build/test/Packager.ut.o build/debug/ClientAddress.o build/debug/Packager.o build/debug/Package.o -g3  -o bin/test/Packager.ut 
build/test/Packager.ut.o: In function `main':
/home/XXX/Documents/dev/cpp/proj/beep/test/Packager.ut.cpp:69: undefined reference to `sf::IpAddress::IpAddress(char const*)'
build/debug/ClientAddress.o: In function `nw::udp::ClientAddress::ClientAddress()':
/home/XXX/Documents/dev/cpp/proj/beep/src/ClientAddress.cpp:21: undefined reference to `sf::IpAddress::IpAddress(char const*)'
build/debug/ClientAddress.o: In function `nw::udp::operator==(nw::udp::ClientAddress const&, nw::udp::ClientAddress const&)':
/home/XXX/Documents/dev/cpp/proj/beep/src/ClientAddress.cpp:33: undefined reference to `sf::operator==(sf::IpAddress const&, sf::IpAddress const&)'
...
```

and so on ... every mentionings of sf:: inside the files are quoted

I get the same error pattern if I try to compile the other tests (for ClientAddress for example)

Of course i now want to know what i linked wrong how there. As you can see the lib is linked with -lsfml-network. I also checked the SMFL installation, so it is at least less likely a lib file gone missing from standard directory.

I guess there is an error in my usage of g++ , compiling and linking orders or smth.

My project tree:

```
>bin
----mainexec
--->test
    ----.ut
>build
--->debug
    ----.o
--->release
    ----.o
--->test
    ----.ut.o
>src
---- .cpp
>include
---- .h
>test
---- .ut.cpp
```

As a second part of the question, I'd like to ask if there is a better way to build tests, because I simply link every src-obj with my test-obj, even if there are way more src-obj linked than it actually needs. It should work and I do not have to maintain my test dependencies all the time, which later would be very cumbersome. What is common ?

Comment: which os? osx? Also version of the g++ compiler.

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: I am  assuming `sfml` means this library https://www.sfml-dev.org. Is it right?

Comment: Objects before libraries on the link line!

Comment: @Anthony Kong this is correct

Comment: @n.m. you're right i  found my answer in your edit ... as my personal mistake goes : i used `COMPILE.cpp` and `LINK.cpp` variables in make which define the order and added my stuff after it. I now have to consider the usage of these Variables.

Answer (score 1):

`sfml-network` has a dependency on `sfml-system`. Try add `-lsfml-system` before `-lsfml-network` in your linker command in your makefile

Comment: It already worked without adding sfml-system at a point(On a flat project structure without make). So I do not think this is true.