# What are LINK.cpp / COMPILE.cpp Variables good for in make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Shortly before I asked this question : [g++ undefined reference to library symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990682/g-undefined-reference-to-library-symbols)

It seems I misused predefined variables of make, namely LINK.cpp.
The error was that I linked the library **before** the objects instead of afterwards.

Now this raised the question what those variables, particularly the LINK.cpp one, are good for because they expand like this :

```
LINK.cpp = $(LINK.cc)
LINK.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
                                          ^
```

I usually store my libs in LDFLAGS variable, which I thought was common, so LINK.cc will always link the libs **before** , because I can add my object files only after, and will cause errors like in the posted question.

Where do I have to put my objects then to use the LINK.cpp variable properly?
Candidates are :

- CXXFLAGS
- CPPFLAGS

,which both seem not to be right.
Have I gotten the use case of the variable wrong ?

To be clear : The question does not aim at the errors a linker can throw at you, but the usage of the variables in make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I usually store my libs in LDFLAGS variable, which I thought was common

It is a fairly common mistake. The conventional meanings of the
make variables that figure in C or C++ compilation are:-

- `CFLAGS`: Compilation options for C
- `CXXFLAGS`: Compilation options for C++
- `CPPFLAGS`: Preprocessor options for C or C++
- `LDFLAGS`: Linkage options, excluding library (`-l`) options
- `LDLIBS`: Libraries or library (`-l`) options for linkage.

These are the meanings assumed in [GNU Make's builtin rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html).

The intended use of the variable:

```
LINK.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

is therefore as in:

```
prog: $(OBJS)
    $(LINK.cc) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

with the libraries *following* the object files.

(The variable `TARGET_ARCH` appears in builtin rules evidently with the
intended meaning *target-architecture options*, but is nontheless undocumented).

Comment: Shame on 90% of the tutorials out there then. Be warned. +1